# nodejs lodash map synchronous requests

Tags: node.js, async-await, lodash, sequence, synchronous

This is the current situation, i have list of payload JSON entry (it could be anything , if you want to try) in the enteries map, i iterate through the map using lodash , and post the requests, in async manner as below

```
_.map(enteries, async (entry) => {
let response_1 = await postToAPI('apiurl', entry);
}
```

Problem :- I tried, with 100 enteries , api can't accept more than 1 request in 1/10 of a second (its a limitation, and can't change :( ), therefore as a workaround, what i thought is two options 
1. i would need to introduce a pause of 100ms , between each requests
2. process them sequentially.

Can someone please assist or advise, how to achieve option 1 or 2 . Any help is greatly appreciated

Updated standalone code :-

```
var _ = require('lodash');

// function for the delay
var delay = function (delayMs) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delayMs);
    });
};

// Create some sample entries
var entries = _.map(_.range(0,20), (i) => {
    return {id: i, name: 'entry #' + i}
});

// Create sample post request returning a promise
async function postToAPI(apiurl, entry) {
    console.log('postToAPI - '+apiurl+ ' request sent = '+ JSON.stringify(entry));
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(entry);
    }); 
};

async function postEntries(entries, allDoneCallback) {
    var responses = [];
    while(entries.length > 0) {
        var entry = entries.shift();
        try
        {
            var response = await postToAPI('apiurl', entry);
            console.log('postToAPI - reply '+ JSON.stringify(entry));
            responses.push(response);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
        }
        await delay(300);
    };

    console.log('postEntries (after posting all the enteries) --> '+responses.length);
    allDoneCallback(responses);
};

postEntries(entries, (res) => { console.log('All done ', res.length);});
```

Comment: You can use [Bluebird map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

Comment: why not send all data into the api at once, reaching the api 100 times for 100 enteries is something you would never want to do. you can read more about promises to check if it can be used in any way. introducing 100 ms delay will make it ultra bulky.

Comment: this job for Bluebird

Comment: as i understand bluebird, would still place all the requests async to the api , and would resolve promise, one by one , based on concurrency attribute. the ask is to stop all the requests sending async. Terry solution has a valid point,  i will understand and test and let you know, kindly let me know if you have any working refererence, so that i can try that in isolation

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that postToAPI returns a promise. 
Posting the entries sequentially will only help if the API takes more than 100 ms to process an an entry. Many APIs will be much quicker than this.

I've revised this method again! Here goes, and I think this really does do what you want!!

```
var delay = function (delayMs) {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          setTimeout(resolve, delayMs);
     });
};


async function postEntries(entries, allDoneCallback) {
    var responses = [];
    while(entries.length > 0) {
        var entry = entries.shift();
        try
        {
            var response = await postToAPI('apiurl', entry);
            responses.push(response);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
        }
        await delay(100);
    };

    console.log(responses);
    allDoneCallback(responses);
};

// Create some sample entries
var entries = _.map(_.range(0,10), (i) => {
   return {id: i, name: 'entry #' + i}
});

postEntries(entries, (res) => { console.log('All done', res);});
```

You could modify the response array to include any errors that occur, you'll note I wrapped the postToAPI in a try/catch block in case any call chokes.

Suggested structure for postToAPI:

```
var postToAPI = function(apiURL, entry) {
    console.log(new Date().getTime(), ' - postToAPI');
        return postHTTP(apiURL, entry).then ((result) => {
            return saveToDB(result);
    });
}
```

Once we have postToAPI in this format, the await will work correctly. I've assumed that postHTTP and saveToDB return promises.

Comment: Thanks Terry, will try it out, Why is that ? "Posting the entries sequentially will only help if the API takes more than 100 ms to process an an entry"

Comment: Another question, will the thread wait at "var intervalID = setInterval(postNextEntry, 100, entries);" for it to finish all requests,  before proceeding further or it will progress further after initiating the postNextEntry function

Comment: Oh because if the API call is quicker than 100 ms, you'll end up calling it again straight away, breaking the rule of calling no more than 10 times per second.

Comment: The thread would continue after setInterval. The best way to proceed would likely be to call a callback function once you've processed all the entries. Just after clearInterval()

Comment: Hi Terry, how it would work for a layman, I am not clear on how it would work in case of fast response <100ms . for example, first request got served in 90ms, would the second request be placed, or it will wait for 10 ms before placing another request, as long the request dont race each other concurrently, i reckon it should work ok. also is there a way for a mandatory wait of 100ms (if the request is completed before) or whenever the request is completed, the next request would follow.  What would happen in this case, if the request takes 500ms to comple, would two requests race each other ?

Comment: Hey @raaone7, with your original code that would be the problem, you call postToAPI, it takes 90ms to return, and since you use await you are going to call it again straight away. I suggested using setInterval to ensure it will be called at most every 100ms. There is a way to put in a mandatory delay after each call, I'll add this to my answer!

Comment: Hi Terry, the new code will introduce same problem after100ms, the way i understand map works is, its all asynchronous, on your updated code, this is how it would behave is my understanding,  say 100 payloads are there in the map, _.map will iterate all of them async and will put in the nodejs processing queue, each record will post the request and wait 100s, to finally resolve, but that won't stop _.map function to process other payload records, since it would be async. Delay would introduce the same problem. let me know if you are available for a call, my emails is ramshyam1982 @ gmail . com

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, it's actually very very tricky to get Node to run code in a synchronous way. Of course this is by design! I would be best then, not to use map but simply iterate through the items using the setInterval approach and the use a callback function called allDone, or something like that to then look at the array of responses.

Comment: I believe the setInterval approach will work, you remove an item from the queue each 100ms and post it, and you are still using asynchronous code!

Comment: I've revised my answer again, I believe it now works as we would like. You might check it out when you get a chance!

Comment: Hi Terry, 
It worked sequentially, but the delay was not respected. attaching the standalone code here.

Comment: Hey @raaone7, that's a funny one, I've tested on Ubuntu with Node 9.4. Here's a link to a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9r2bqaz5/#&togetherjs=ncOEQFIqQb, could you give this a whirl? Ta!

Comment: Hi Gareth, 

Thanks Heaps ! It worked as expected, It was my bad, i put 200ms and was expecting 2 s :) 

one issue observed, before the the last request was finished, the callback was finished. 

the post method on average takes around 3s.

Comment: Great, looks pretty good. It's odd the callback would be fired this might be an off by one error. Ok, that makes some sense..I will have a look!

Comment: I can't see this error on my side, is the postToAPI function marked as async? It should not be async!

Comment: I've tried on Windows 7 Node.js 8.9.4, I'm not seeing the callback issue!

Comment: postToAPI is marked as async, since it makes other calls as well, like updating the db , and uses await within that. i ran a request , with 11 requests, callback got resolved after 8 requests , while other 3 were in progress.  :(  How can we enforce the call back to finish after all the promises are resolved.  may be something like Promise.all (....)

Comment: Promise.all is exactly what you want!

Comment: I'd suggest that postToAPI should return an array of promises and then you do await Promise.all(postToAPI()). You could then remove the async keyword from it!

Comment: Essentially async is like Promise.then, the problem is you can only use await with a function that returns a promise. So when you await a function that is async it will lead to some weird behaviour!. What we're trying to do here is nest async functions. If you want to do multiple operations within postToAPI, I'd either use a then pattern (which I'll illustrate in the answer or I'd include the delay function within postToAPI!